# Android WebView custom action on html button of a web page

Tags: android, html, button, webview

I have loaded a web page in WebView via `WebView.loadData()`.

Now I want to ad custom action to a button of that webpage from the WebView (Like, when I click the button, it will behave differently from the original webpage).

Is it possible from WebView? If possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can try something like this

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
                {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("your url"))
                        {
                                  // your code 
                                  return true;
                        }

                    return false;
                }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
        }
```

Don't forget to add myWebClient to your webView

Comment: Thumbs UP for this perfect answer. Thanks a lot @subasa. This is exactly what I wanted and it works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's no possible. You can only **webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());**

```
 private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url...) // your logic here
        return true;
    }
```